# Hide tables in Oracle XE database

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I'm using Oracle XE but I would like to log in as a user than can create tables, contraints etc., but who cannot view all of the other system tables and stuff that you see when you log in with the system account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new user with:

```
CREATE USER xxx IDENTIFIED BY yyyy;
```

From there, issue GRANT for the privileges you want to give the user:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO xxx;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO xxx;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO xxx;
```

etc.

See the [SQL Reference](http://file:///C:/oracle/Doc/11g/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9013.htm#i2155015) documentation for all the privileges you can grant. User xxx will only be able to see their own objects and objects they have been granted privileges on.